# Checking remote file permission using ACLs inconsistant behaviour

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, acl

I want to check the file permissions of a remote file for the current user. However I was getting inconsistent behaviour when using Qt's [`QFileInfo`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfileinfo.html#ntfs-permissions) class. A file on one network location would report that it was readable while the same file on another network location would report that it was not readable even though both were readable in reality.

After digging through the implementation it seems as though what is happening when the function 'succeed' is [`GetNamedSecurityInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446645%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is setting the pointer to an ACL (`pDacl`) to null which apparently only happens if the security descriptor does not contain an ACL and when the `DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION` flag is passed in. This especially shouldn't happen as the function's error code is reporting success. The null ACL pointer is then passed in to [`GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446637%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which results in it setting its `ACCESS_MASK` parameter to full permissions. The documentation doesn't seem to say what the expected behaviour of `GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl` is when passed a null pointer to an ACL (`pacl`) but I'm surprised that reporting full access is what appears to happen. It also returns `ERROR_SUCCESS` instead of `ERROR_INVALID_ACL` which is what I would expect.

When the function 'fails' `GetNamedSecurityInfo` returns an actual pointer to an ACL which when passed to `GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl` results in the `ACCESS_MASK` being set to no access even though the current user should have full access.

When dealing with files on the local system everything works as I would expect it to with ACLs being returned and permissions reported correctly.

I read on the documentation page for `GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl` that its use is deprecated, however the recommended alternative method exhibits exactly the same behaviour as this.

I have written a small example program using just the Win32 API which reproduces the problem.

```
#include "Aclapi.h"

const wchar_t* files[] =
{
    L"\\\\?\\UNC\\share1\\fileThatSucceeds.txt",
    L"\\\\?\\UNC\\share2\\fileThatFails.txt" 
};

int main(void)
{
    TRUSTEE_W currentUserTrusteeW;
    PSID currentUserSID = 0;
    HANDLE hnd = ::GetCurrentProcess();
    HANDLE token = 0;
    if (::OpenProcessToken(hnd, TOKEN_QUERY, &token)) {
        DWORD retsize = 0;
        ::GetTokenInformation(token, TokenUser, 0, 0, &retsize);
        if (retsize) {
            void *tokenBuffer = malloc(retsize);
            if (::GetTokenInformation(token, TokenUser, tokenBuffer, retsize, &retsize)) {
                PSID tokenSid = ((PTOKEN_USER)(tokenBuffer))->User.Sid;
                DWORD sidLen = ::GetLengthSid(tokenSid);
                currentUserSID = (PSID)(malloc(sidLen));
                if (::CopySid(sidLen, currentUserSID, tokenSid))
                    BuildTrusteeWithSid(&currentUserTrusteeW, currentUserSID);
            }
            free(tokenBuffer);
        }
        ::CloseHandle(token);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        wchar_t* file = (wchar_t*)files[i];
        PSID pOwner = 0;
        PSID pGroup = 0;
        PACL pDacl = 0;
        PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR pSD;
        DWORD res = GetNamedSecurityInfoW(file, SE_FILE_OBJECT, 
            OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION | GROUP_SECURITY_INFORMATION | DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
            &pOwner, &pGroup, &pDacl, 0, &pSD);
        if (res == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
            ACCESS_MASK mask;
            res = GetEffectiveRightsFromAclW(pDacl, &currentUserTrusteeW, &mask);
            if (res == ERROR_SUCCESS)
            {
                wprintf(file);
                printf(" Permissions:\n");
                if (((mask & GENERIC_READ) == GENERIC_READ)
                || ((mask & FILE_GENERIC_READ) == FILE_GENERIC_READ))
                    wprintf_s(L"\tRead\n");
                if (((mask & GENERIC_WRITE) == GENERIC_WRITE)
                || ((mask & FILE_GENERIC_WRITE) == FILE_GENERIC_WRITE))
                    wprintf_s(L"\tWrite\n");
                if (((mask & GENERIC_EXECUTE) == GENERIC_EXECUTE)
                || ((mask & FILE_GENERIC_EXECUTE) == FILE_GENERIC_EXECUTE))
                    wprintf_s(L"\tExecute\n");
            }
        }
    }
    free(currentUserSID);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

**Edit:** When I run

```
ConvertSecurityDescriptorToStringSecurityDescriptor(pSD, SDDL_REVISION_1, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, &StringSecurityDescriptor, &StringSecurityDescriptorLen);
```

as suggested in the comments I get the following output for the file that 'succeeds': `D:NO_ACCESS_CONTROL` and for the file that 'fails': `D:(A;ID;0x1301ff;;;S-1-5-21-4567658000-3444563456-7654345676-3475)(A;ID;0x1301ff;;;S-1-5-21-4567658000-3444563456-7654345676-4576)...`.

Both the servers are NAS using communicating using CIFS.

Comment: I'd advise avoiding this route entirely. Just open the file and try to read (or write, or whatever). Even after you figure out the problem you're seeing right now, the basic technique has a race condition (i.e., if you check access, then try to carry out an operation, the rights could change after you checked them, so the data you collected was stale anyway).

Comment: Please use ConvertSecurityDescriptorToStringSecurityDescriptor to turn `pSD` into a string, print it, then copy and paste the output into your question.  (FWIW, the behaviour you describe for the file that is working is normal if the file does not have a DACL.  But that's unusual.  What sort of server is it?  Windows, Samba, a NAS?)

Comment: @HarryJohnston I've added the information you asked about.

Comment: In addition to what @JerryCoffin has said, you are (a) running the risk of testing different things from what the OS will test, *or* (b) testing exactly the same things the OS will test, and therefore simply duplicating its work. At the wrong time. Don't do this.

Comment: OK.  The parts of the string starting S-1-5-21 are SIDs, identifying either users or groups.  Please call `ConvertSidToStringSid` on `currentUserTrusteeW->ptstrName` and print the SID whose rights you are testing.  Does that SID appear in the security descriptor string?  (If so, please post the relevant part of the string, everything between the parenthesis.)